# Optimize/build modules under parallel directories using the same config file in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have a feeling that the title just might not be explanatory :)

**Setup**

Suppose that I have the following structure:

[image]

where `app.js` files are main bootstrapping/entry modules for the applications that look like this:

**app01**

```
require.config({});

require([
    'app/component1.js'
], 
function(component){
    // do something with component1
});
```

**app02**

```
require.config({});

require([
    'app/component2.js'
], 
function(component){
    // do something with component2
});
```

which both work with appropriate `index.html` files.

I have a RequireJS build configuration file (assume correct placement related to the paths) for **app01**:

```
({
    appDir: 'apps/app01',
    baseUrl: '.',
    dir: 'built_apps/app01',
    optimize: 'closure',
    paths: {
    },

    modules: [
        {
            name: 'app'
        }
    ]
})
```

which works just fine. Similar file (replacing `app01` with `app02`) works just fine for **app02**.

**Problem/target**

Now I want to be able to run RequireJS build tool (using Google Closure with Rhino under Ant, not that it really matters in this case) for both **app01** and **app02** applications using **the same** build configuration file **and, preferably, without actually listing all the apps by name (since the number and names may vary over time).**

Basically I expect (or rather hope) to have something like this:

```
({
    appDir: 'apps',
    baseUrl: '.',
    dir: 'built_apps',
    optimize: 'closure',
    paths: {

    },

    modules: [
        {
            name: 'app*/app' // notice the wildcard
        }
    ]
})
```

which would run over `built_apps` directory, find all apps under app*/app and optimize each one of them.

I know I can use Ant to create such build configuration file on the fly per app, run build against it and then clean up, but I'd rather have RequireJS solution.

**Is there a way to do something like this with RequireJS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in wildcarding configuration for RequireJS.  One way or another, you'll need code to do this.  I'll observe that what you're asking for here amounts to translating a wildcard into some kind of implicit iteration on the module objects, akin to what [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) provides for its templates.  IMO, that's a fairly brittle and limited approach in this context.

Instead, I recommend generating your `modules` array programmatically in JavaScript right in the build config. Recall, the build config is JavaScript not just a JSON data structure. This gives you sophisticated scripting capabilities there.

I've done this kind of scripting in the build config for the [requirejs-rails gem](https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails/).  Here's an [example gist](https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails/) that shows what `r.js` would see at build time.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. As you may have noticed by my second question, I moved on to the declarative approach. Thank you.