# How to build several modules using RequireJS using one physical configuration file with overrides

Tags: javascript, build, requirejs

I have been battling with this for a while (even used some Ant-based workarounds), even posted a question that went unanswered: [older similar/related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982133/optimize-build-modules-under-parallel-directories-using-the-same-config-file-in).

Require.js allows to build several modules using the same profile/config file. For example:

```
({
    appDir: 'some/path',
    baseUrl: 'some/base/path',
    dir: 'some/other/path',
    optimize: 'none',
    paths: {
        ...
    },

    modules: [
    {
        name: 'someModule',
    },
    {
        name: 'someOtherModule'
    }]
})
```

Which works fairly well. Additionally, Require.js provides an option to override any option for the build for a specific module: [Require/js example build configuration](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L225), like this :

```
({
    appDir: 'some/path',
    baseUrl: 'some/base/path',
    dir: 'some/other/path',
    optimize: 'none',
    paths: {
        ...
    },

    modules: [
    {
        name: 'someModule',
    },
    {
        name: 'someModule',
        override : {
            optimize: 'uglify'
        }
    }]
})
```

or so I understood it. The purpose is to use the same build configuration file on the same application, but have it both non-minified and minified. **This doesn't work.**

**EDIT**
The error I am getting is (cleaned up, since it is part of a larger Ant build):

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'some/other/path/someModule.js-temp'
```

Any help, suggestions (on both questions) are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify what "this doesn't work" means?

Comment: Sure. It doesn't run the second module using uglify. Is it supposed to and I miss something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listing of modules: config does not allow duplicates for the name value. I suspect that is the source of the problem. It is an array just to allow proper sequencing of build layers that may be excluded in other build layers -- using an object hash would not work since key iteration on an object does not guarantee order.

If you want to do a build that has the layer in non-minified and minified format, I suggest driving the build via a node script, then manually requiring uglify and doing a copy of the built file and minification of that copy after the build.

Here is an example of a node script that drives the build:
https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/tests/tools/override/override.js

That one is replacing the version of uglify used, but you could use it and do the file copy/manual minification in the callback function passed to requirejs.optimize().

Comment: Wouldn't such an approach force me to install the requirejs npm package? Is there a way to avoid that? Assume that I want to be able to do the same using Rhino and Closure?

Comment: You do not need npm install requirejs, just require('../path/to/r.js') to load it in a node program.

Comment: Thank you, James. I'll manage the solution for Rhino somehow.

Comment: The new link appears to be https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/tests/tools/override/override.js